Keras: How to input and output multiclass y attribute
So I have a dataset where the target y attribute is a category (multiclass) and I am trying to input it into a Keras model and output the same multiclass category when I use the predict function.  Normally I am doing binary classification but this doesn't work the same way.
From what I have read, you have to encode this multiclass y attribute before you predict with it, with Keras "to_categorical()" function, which creates an array of a list of lists.  I have five classes and this step works fine.
The problem is that I cannot get this into the Keras model without some kind of error, no matter what I do.  I have even converted this y array into a dataframe of the y attribute where values are the encoded lists (a single target attribute) and the model errors out by claiming it is still a multi-dimensional array.
The x attributes are also encoded, so there are 200 attributes for x.  I get that the encoded floats for x will each be an attribute, so I am confused of how you have to encode a multiclass y target in the same way if it results in multiple attributes too.  And if I turn these lists into a single attribute (as describe above), Keras still treats it as an array of lists.  And if I do not encode at all, then I get continuous predictions and the model itself is probably flawed by not having the categorical input.
So how should this actually be done?

# y_train_HCb = pd.DataFrame(y_train_HCb)
y_train_HCbc = to_categorical(y_train_HCb, num_classes=None)
# y_train_HCbc
# type(y_train_HCb)

y_train_HCbcd = pd.DataFrame(y_train_HCbc)
type(y_train_HCbcd)

y_train_HCbcd['product'] = pd.Series(list(y_train_HCbc))
y_train_HCbcd

y_train_HCbf = pd.DataFrame(y_train_HCbcd['product'])
y_train_HCbf


model_HCb = Sequential()

# maxlen = 200
model_HCb.add(Embedding(10000, 32, input_length=maxlen))
model_HCb.add(GRU(16, activation='relu'))
model_HCb.add(Flatten())
model_HCb.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_HCb.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model_HCb.summary()

history = model_HCb.fit(x_train_HCb, y_train_HCbf, epochs=3, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.2)


